# Is it possible to delete elements from matlab matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matlab matrix in the form

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6; 1 1 2 2 3 3; 1 2 3 3 2 1]
```

Is it possible to delete the 4th, 5th and 6th columns of the matrix A so that the result would be:

```
A = [1 2 3; 1 1 2; 1 2 3]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would do it:

```
A(:,4:6)=[];
```

Comment: Also, if he wants to delete only columns 4 and 6 (as stated in the text but not in the result), he should do `A(:,[4 6])=[]`

Answer (score 1):

```
octave-3.4.0:1> A = [1 2 3 4 5 6; 1 1 2 2 3 3; 1 2 3 3 2 1]
A =

   1   2   3   4   5   6
   1   1   2   2   3   3
   1   2   3   3   2   1

octave-3.4.0:2> A = A(:,1:3)
A =

   1   2   3
   1   1   2
   1   2   3
```